# Angular styles missing for material UI

Tags: angular-material

I'm learning from Angular Material and I have problem on my machine.

When I'm trying to reproduce any of component from angular material site :
[Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)
The result is like below:


[image]

I've also tried the same example using [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and result is correct.

[image]


 In Both cases I don't provide any styles. Just based on library.

Is it common problem?

Stakblitz has angular 15, my local project also.

Thank's for any advice.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" matInput [formControl]="searchControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" class="center">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let result of filteredResults | async" [value]="result" class="center">
    {{ result.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: It looks like the styles are missing. Do you use a pre-built theme, or a custom theme? Either way, you should have a look into the [getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) and [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). Also a stackblitz of the working solution is not very helpful, please provide a reproduction for the case that it's **not** working.

Comment: Just generated new Angular project 

html:
`<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" matInput [formControl]="searchControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" class="center">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let result of filteredResults | async" [value]="result" class="center">
        {{ result.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>`

ts of component is not important. That's all I have. All Themes are default from fact the project is basically new

Comment: I'm new in frontend world so probably I'm doing basic mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to import the scss files as well. More info can be found in the getting started guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: `ng add @angular/material` was solution. Thanks!